# Creating n functions with n corresponding variables in python?

Tags: python, function

I would like to create n functions, specified by an integer given by the user. I have heard that it is not good to dynamically create variables and indeed when i tried to create variables and subsequent functions with a for loop the code doesn't produce my result. At any rate, what i want to do is create a function that is the sum of n exponentials, such as if n=3 I get three functions:

```
user_input_n = 3

f1(A1,k1,time) = A1*np.exp(-k1*time)
f2(A2,k2,time) = A2*np.exp(-k2*time) 
f3(A3,k3,time) = A3*np.exp(-k3*time)
```

and the corresponding variables:

```
A1,A2,A3,k1,k2,k3
```

in some usable matrices:

```
Atotal=[A1,A2,A3]; 
ktotal=[k1,k2,k3]
```

which can be combined to fit data as:

```
ftotal(A1,A2,A3,k1,k2,k3,time)= f1(A1,k1,time) + f2(A2,k2,time) + f3(A3,k3,time)
```

Does anybody have a reasonable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your question then you'll want to use array inputs to create the functions. I found that using a combination of sympy/numpy is the most straight forward solution:

```
#lambdify method (probably the easiest)
from numpy import *
from sympy import *
from numpy import array
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot
A=array([1,2,3])
k=array([4,5,6])
tt=linspace(0,5)#time tt
t=symbols('t')
ff=lambdify(t,dot(A,exp(1)**(-k*t)))
#note that exp(-k*t) creates an exp array which doesn't work.
#thats why it is important to use exp(1)**-k*t instead
plot(tt,ff(tt))
#note that ff input must be an array. a list won't work
```